# calculate difference between two timings in minutes in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and i am a salesforce developer.
How to calculate difference between two timings in minutes in MYSQL.

```
(L1_Finish_TimeStamp__c - L1_Start_TimeStamp__c)
```

I tried:

```
Timediff(L1_Finish_TimeStamp__c, L1_Start_TimeStamp__c)/144
```

But it is not working correctly. Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(unix_timestamp(L1_Finish_TimeStamp__c)-unix_timestamp(L1_Start_TimeStamp__c))/60
```

As far as I assume `L1_Finish_TimeStamp__c` and `L1_Start_TimeStamp__c` contains timestamps in format like `2017-08-16 09:29:21`, hence we have convert it into `unix timestamp` which is integer value and contains seconds so we have divide difference to 60.

Comment: @dhana Happy to help!)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the difference using below query :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'timestampcolumn1','timestampcolumn2') FROM TableName
```

both columns should be of same datatype